# JQuery/JavaScript not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

The script below is not running in IE7, but it's working in Chrome and Firefox. Once user clicks change password, nothing happens in IE.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#closebtn").click(function () {
        $("#dlg").hide('800', "swing", function () { $("#bkg").fadeOut("500"); });
    });


    $("#opn").click(function () {
        if (document.getElementById('bkg').style.visibility == 'hidden') {
            document.getElementById('bkg').style.visibility = '';
            $("#bkg").hide();
        }
        if (document.getElementById('dlg').style.visibility == 'hidden') {
            document.getElementById('dlg').style.visibility = '';
            $("#dlg").hide();
        }
        $("#bkg").fadeIn(500, "linear", function () { $("#dlg").show(800, "swing"); });
        return false;
    });

});
</script>


  <div id="Accountdisplay">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Accountdetail", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
     {

     <table align="left" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="5">
     <tr><td class="editor-label" >
      User Name:
     </td><td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)
      </td></tr>
      <tr>
   <td class="editor-label">
   Email Id:
</td>
<td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email_Id)
  </td></tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="editor-label">
  Division:
   </td>
   <td>
   @Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.Division)
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="editor-label">
User Type:
</td>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.User_Type)
</td></tr>
<tr><td>

<a href="#" id="opn" rel="nofollow">Change Password</a>

  @*<div >
   @Html.ActionLink("[Change Password]",null,"Home",new {id="opn",style =    
  "color:white"})
</div>*@
</td></tr>

</table>

}
</div>


<div class="blockbkg" id="bkg" style="visibility: hidden;">
<div class="cont" id="dlg" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <div class="closebtn" title="Close" id="closebtn"></div>
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Logon", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
  {
   <table>
   <tr>
   <td>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password) 
   </td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { Style =         
   "width:65%;height:25px;font-size:1.05em" }) </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Confirm_Password) 
   </td>
   <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Confirm_Password, new { Style = "width:65%;height:25px;font-size:1.05em" }) </td>
   </tr>



   </table>   

  }
 </div>
 </div>

       my css:
          #Accountdisplay 
          {
       background-color:Gray;
         color:Black;
        width:50%;
         border:1px solid black;
        height:80%;
          padding: 20px;
           margin-left:200px;
          margin-top:10px;
            }
          .blockbkg {
           background-color: black;

          background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.90);
          width: 100%;
          min-height: 100%;
           overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
}
.cont {
  background-color:Green;
  color:White;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 20px;
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 35%;


  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;

}
.closebtn 
  {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  float: right;
  top: 0;

  background-color:Gray;
  display: block;
   }

        .closebtn:hover 
        {
        cursor: pointer;
          }
```

here i added my css also. still i cant find why its not working in IE 7, shall i change the IE vesrion and check ???? 
   thanks in advance,

Comment: Is ther any console error?

Comment: no console error also.

Comment: @anoop, console in IE7? :-)

Comment: speaking about console in firefox.

Comment: you can emulate ie7 from ie9. there you can use the console.

Comment: Should there be trailing semicolons for the TextBox styles (font-size:1.05em..)?

Comment: i want to do it in below IE7 version only.in IE 6 also its not coming, any comma related prob in script?

Comment: Have you tried setting any breakpoints or alerts to see if the click event functions are actually run? Also, if you could output the **rendered** HTML that'd be nicer...

Comment: Please, provide us your page source

Comment: i checked with break point also, once i click the link[change password] its not going inside of java script also. but i dont know how its working in Chrome and firefox.

Comment: How can you press [Change Password] link? It's commented.

Comment: anchor tag is there right, using that only.

Comment: try to print/alert `document.getElementById('bkg').style.visibility && document.getElementById('dlg').style.visibility`. It may give you some pointers.

Comment: and also `document.getElementById` is available in IE 7?

Comment: try using `$('#bkg').css('visibility')` instead of `document.getElementById('bkg').style.visibility`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry... i´m not able to add a comment... :/

Where is the jquery-script-tag located? Within the head or somewhere in the body?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see exactly what could be the problem, but this piece of code sticks out as odd and should be changed to fully use jQuery.

```
$("#opn").click(function () {
    /*
    if (document.getElementById('bkg').style.visibility == 'hidden') {
        document.getElementById('bkg').style.visibility = '';
        $("#bkg").hide();
    }
    if (document.getElementById('dlg').style.visibility == 'hidden') {
        document.getElementById('dlg').style.visibility = '';
        $("#dlg").hide();
    }
    */
    $("#bkg,#dlg").css("visibility", "").hide(); // does the same thing as above

    $("#bkg").fadeIn(500, "linear", function () { $("#dlg").show(800, "swing"); });
    return false;
});
```

On another note, unless you really need `bgk` and `dlg` to have layout on page load, but being invisible, you should use `display:none;` instead, it is what `hide` and `show` use to toggle an element's visiblity (through `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` as well).

Comment: i changed like this now also working in firefox and chrome not in IE.'<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function ()
     {
        $("#closebtn").click(function () {
            $("#dlg").hide('800', "swing", function () { $("#bkg").fadeOut("500"); });
        });


        $("#opn").click(function ()
        {

            $("#bkg,#dlg").css("visibility", "").hide();
            $("#bkg").fadeIn('500', "linear", function () { $("#dlg").show('800', "swing"); });
            return false;
        });

    });
  </script>'

Comment: onclick is not firing.'<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#opn").click(function ()
     {
        alert('clciked successfully');

    });

  
  </script>'

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("[Change Password]",null,"Home",new {id="opn",style = "color:white"})

Comment: if you do `alert($("#opn").length);` what does it output? It should be `1`. If so, try changing `$("#opn").click(function() ...` for `$("#opn").on("click", function() ...`.